# SSIS package performance enhancement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I have a log table that I am planning to import from my Transaction Database to my reporting Database.

The columns of the table are as follows:

```
Id,Varchar1 , Varchar2, Time1, Time2
```

XML structures are stored in Varchar1 & varchar2

I am using a SSIS package and a data flow task with an OLEDB source and destination.

There are close to 600000 records in the table and its taking an extremely long time to transfer.

The queries that I tried so far in my OLEDB source are :

1)`select Id, XML1, XML2, Time1, Time2 where Time > 'XXXX' and Time2 < 'XXXX'`

Converting Varchar to xml 
2)

```
select Id, CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Varchar1, 0)), CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),Varchar2, 0))
, Time1, Time2 where Time > 'XXXX' and Time2 < 'XXXX'
```

Both the queries take me an extremely long time.

Does anyone have a better solution/approach to achieve my task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you determine whether it's the retrieving of the data from the source db or the writing of the data to the destination db that's causing the delay?

If you have triggers or indexes on the destination table, that could be part of the delay.  You might want to disable them while your import is going on.

Is this going to be a one-time transfer or will you be performing repeated transfers of similar numbers of records?

Comment: Hi Ann Thank you ! There are going to be multiple transfers, one transfer each month. There are no triggers or indexes on the destination table yet. You have raised a vaild point to determine whether the source or the destination is causing the dealy . I am wondering how I can find that info ?

Comment: You could try running the query in SSMS and see how long it takes to return 600K rows. While it won't be a perfect replica of transfer conditions, it will have the effect of isolating the source query.

Comment: You might also want to make sure you have plenty of disk space on the server this data is going to. The tighter the space it has to fit in, the slower things will go.

Comment: Finally, the converting to XML is probably going to add time, since it has to make sure that the string it's converting to XML is well-formed XML.

Comment: Thanks for the Pointers Ann ! I will check back and let you know.

Comment: @SqlSamurai So how did it turn out?  If I helped you solve the problem, please consider marking my answer as your accepted one.  Thanks!